# How do I render two html documents per action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After user push save button, I need to **render** new page and **render_to_string** preview of this page in same time. To store it into DB.

So i got DoubleRenderError exception.

I try to stub @performed?

But Layouts purging after first render. Any ideas?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: I see few solutions:
- Create callback to other action
- Create separate controller to precess this rending

Comment: a few things come to mind -- can you say more about why you want to store a page preview in the database?

Comment: With pleasure!
I should send this html as e-mail to user. So I should render preview of this page.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used both render_to_string and render on the same request.

I think you need to make sure you call render_to_string first.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this using rack middleware.

```
class ResponseLoggerMiddleware
    def initialize(app)
        @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
        status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
        ... save your response to the database ...    
        [status, headers, response]
    end
end
```

You can install it like this:

```
# environment.rb
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
    ...
    config.middleware.use ResponseLoggerMiddleware
end
```